# How to filter an email type to prevent it from occupying even the spam folder?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, email-filter

I receive daily messages in my Gmail with the same subject: "Sales Boom".
Gmail correctly detects these messages as spam and sends them correctly to the spam folder.
Even so, I would like to know if it is possible to create a filter to permanently delete these messages that are already in the spam folder, as these are messages that do not even need to be analyzed?

Comment: Google is your friend>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>https://internet.gadgethacks.com/how-to/automatically-delete-spam-messages-gmail-0139569/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Moab comment, I got the clue to solving this question, once the [link](https://internet.gadgethacks.com/how-to/automatically-delete-spam-messages-gmail-0139569/) in his comment has out of date instructions, so, to help to the community, here are the up to date information to get this working:

1. Inside Gmail, click on the dropdown button of the "Search Mail" field:
   [image]
2. Insert the subject you want to filter (or any other field you think are the correct), and, MOST IMPORTANT, write `in:spam` inside the "has the words" filter, then click on "create filter:
   [image]
3. You'll get this warning, just clik OK:
   [image]
4. In the next screen, select `delete it` and click "Create Filter":
   [image]

That's it!

If you want to confirm (or change) the created filter.

1. Click on the "gear" button and then click on "settings":
   [image]
2. Click on "Filters and Blocked Addresses":
   [image]
3. Finally, locate the last created filter and you'll get to change it if you want:
   [image]

Comment: IMHO it would be much safer to "mark as read" and "apply custom label e.g. 'auto-read'" instead of deleting.  It should spare you inspecting unread spam with leaving a safety net. AFAIR gmail deletes spam after 30 days anyway.